# Loop the JButton in three color when clicked?

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

How can i change the JButton color to loop to green,yellow,white when it is clicked? if i click it must go to yellow ,click again then white, click again then changes to green and so on.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
     countClick++;       
    switch (countClick) 
    {
        case 0:
            m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).setBackground(Color.yellow);
            break;
        case 1:
            m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).setBackground(Color.yellow);
            break;

        case 2:
            m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).setBackground(Color.red);
            countClick =0;
    }

}
```

What if the button is already yellow then i have to click it twice.
Note:
The Button are stored in the array list. and i used loop to add it to the grid layout. the colored are read from the text file. This is how i added the JBUtton on GridlLayout. This is in another class.

```
 btn = new ArrayList<>();

        while((text = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            tmp=text.split(",");

            for(int i=0; i<tmp.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(tmp[i]);

                switch (tmp[i]) 
                {
                    case "0":
                        btn.add( i,new JButton() );
                        btn.get(i).setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                        btn.get(i).setEnabled(false);
                        newPanel.add(btn.get(i));
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        btn.add( i,new JButton("A") );
                        btn.get(i).addMouseListener(new controller(this));
                        newPanel.add(btn.get(i));
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        btn.add( i,new JButton("G") );
                        btn.get(i).setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        btn.get(i).addMouseListener(new controller(this));
                        newPanel.add(btn.get(i));
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        btn.add( i,new JButton("Y") );
                        btn.get(i).setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        btn.get(i).addMouseListener(new controller(this));
                        newPanel.add(btn.get(i));
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        btn.add( i,new JButton("R") );
                        btn.get(i).setBackground(Color.RED);
                        btn.get(i).addMouseListener(new controller(this));
                        newPanel.add(btn.get(i));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: simply add an actionlistener to the button, that changes the colors.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
private int countClicks =0;

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         countClicks++;
         switch (countClicks){
              case 0:
                  boutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                  break;
              case 1:
                  boutton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                  break;
              case 2:
                  boutton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                  countClicks=0;
                  break;
     }
```

Comment: what if  the button is already yellow, then i have to click it twice??

Comment: Just store colors in a HashMap with the color as they key, then always color the button the next element within the map and if there's no next element, go back to the first?

Could probably also do it with LinkedList or something.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, because it let you easily change the colors and re-use the "color changer" with other buttons.

```
public  class ButtonBackgroundColorChanger implements ActionListener {
    private int actualColorIndex = 0;
    private Color[] colors;

    public ButtonBackgroundColorChanger(Color... colors) {
        if (colors.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "At least one color must be provided");
        }
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        AbstractButton abstractButton = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();

        Color nextColor = nextColor();
        abstractButton.setBackground(nextColor);
    }

    private Color nextColor() {
        Color actualColor = colors[actualColorIndex++];
        actualColorIndex = actualColorIndex % colors.length;
        return actualColor;
    }

}
```

Then use it, e.g.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        ButtonBackgroundColorChanger buttonBackgroundColorChanger1 = new ButtonBackgroundColorChanger(
                Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN);
        AbstractButton button1 = new JButton("click to change color");
        contentPane.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(buttonBackgroundColorChanger1);

        ButtonBackgroundColorChanger buttonBackgroundColorChanger2 = new ButtonBackgroundColorChanger(
                Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA);
        AbstractButton button2 = new JButton("click to change color");
        contentPane.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(buttonBackgroundColorChanger2);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    if(Color.green==( m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).getBackground()))
    {
        m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    else if(Color.red==( m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).getBackground()))
    {
        m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
    else if(Color.yellow==( m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).getBackground()))
    {
        m.btn.get(m.btn.indexOf(e.getSource())).setBackground(Color.green);
    }

}
```

i guess this will do for now, sorry for the trouble guys.